C#. how can i get my code to chose a random variable for me and then add 1 to it?
Im trying to create a code that can randomly generate a character sheet for me in my TTRPG. but to do that i need it to chose a random Stat from a list of 6 and add 1 to its value for every level that the character is. Im not sure how to get it to randomly choose a variable for me though.
my current code is this:
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "Kahs World";
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WindowHeight = 40;
        //Above is the settings for the window pop up
        MakeCharacter();
        
        //Below says that the window won't close unless there is a button press
        Console.WriteLine("End Program?\n (Y/N)");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }   

    static void MakeCharacter()
    {
        Random numberGen = new Random();
        System.Console.WriteLine("Name your character.");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        int age = numberGen.Next(20, 151);
        int Level = numberGen.Next(1, 21);
        int PHY = numberGen.Next(3, 21);
        int ADR = numberGen.Next(3, 21);
        int COG = numberGen.Next(3, 21);
        int SPE = numberGen.Next(3, 21);
        int CHA = numberGen.Next(3, 21);
        int TEC = numberGen.Next(3, 21);
        Console.WriteLine(name + "\n Level " + Level+ "\n  PHY: " + PHY + " ADR: " + ADR + " COG: " + COG + " SPE: " + SPE + " CHA: " + CHA + " TEC: " + TEC);
    }
}

im not really sure where to start on this one I've tried just doing a normal sting list but that wouldn't actually pick a variable.

Sorry, not following.  What's a TTRPG, a character sheet and a random Stat? What do you mean by pick a variable? OK, it looks like TTRPG is a table-top role-play game. But what do you mean by add 1 to its value for every level that the character is?

Read up on C# dictionaries.

I'm making a randomly generated character in a game so i need to have things like the strength, wisdom and intelligence values for the character chosen from 1-20. that i already have done, now i need for the code to randomly choose from six of these attributes and increase its value by one for example increasing the strength value from 1 to 2. and then i need it to repeat this stem a random number of times

Lets start by creating an actual character class. I will in this example limit myself to two attributes to keep things shorter:
public class Character
{
    public int PHY { get; set; } = 6;
    public int ADR { get; set; } = 6;
}

But we also want a way to refer to the attribute type, one way to do this is with an enum:
public enum Attribute
{
    PHY,
    ADR
}

And the next step is to connect the attribute properties of our character with the attribute enum, somehow. There are several possible ways to do this, but one is a pair of switches:
public int this[Attribute attribute]
{
    get =>
        attribute switch
        {
            Attribute.PHY => PHY,
            Attribute.ADR => ADR,
            _             => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(attribute), attribute, null)
        };
    set
    {
        switch (attribute)
        {
            case Attribute.PHY: PHY = value; break;
            case Attribute.ADR: ADR = value; break;
            default:            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(attribute), attribute, null);
        }
    }
}

This way I can do myCharacter[Attribute.PHY]++ to increment a specific attribute. To increment a random attribute we can just list all the values from the Attribute enum, and select a random one. We can encapsulate this into a LevelUp-method in the character class:
public void LevelUp()
{
    var random = new Random();
    var allAttributes = (Attribute[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Attribute));
    var attributeToIncement = allAttributes[random.Next(0, allAttributes.Length)];
    this[attributeToIncement]++;
}

